# OSGI can't find restlet class

Tags: eclipse, jetty, osgi, restlet

**Hi,all
I just come cross a problem: The OSGI can't start for it can't find the class :org/restlet/engine/adapter/HttpServerHelper
but i have add it in anywhere(src,import-packes,plugins),but still get this errors,anyone can help me ?! thanks**

> !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator XXX.Activator for
>   bundle XXXX is invalid    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/restlet/engine/adapter/HttpServerHelper   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:456)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  ... 34 more

Answer (score 0):

Probably your bundle doesn't import the package `org.restlet.engine.adapter`.

Comment: yeah,but i indeed add the bundle in my "Imported_Packages": in my "plug-in Dependeces" shows: D:\Eclipse3.7\plugins\org.restlet_2.1.0.snapshot-v20111127-2200.jar"

Comment: I don't think so, what does your `MANIFEST.MF` look like?

Comment: Your Restlet edition for OSGi looks a bit old, could you try again with 2.1 RC6?